# Django query to compare two foreignkey fields?

Tags: django

I have these sample database models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = CharField()
    price = IntegerField()

class Author(models.Model):
    name = CharField()
    book = ForeignKey(Book, related_name='authors')
    type = CharField(choices=('high','medium','low'))

class Random(models.Model):
    book = Foreignkey(Book, related_name='randoms')
    type = CharField(choices=('high','medium','low'))
    rank = PositiveIntegerField()
```

Database Objects:-

1. b1 = Book('book1', 25)
2. b2 = Book('book2', 30)
3. Author('author1', b1, 'high')
4. Author('author2', b1, 'medium')
5. Author('author3', b1, 'medium')
6. Author('author4', b2, 'low')
7. Author('author5', b2, 'low')
8. Author('author6', b2, 'low')
9. Random(b1, 'high', 1)
10. Random(b1, 'medium', 2)
11. Random(b1, 'low', 5)
12. Random(b2, 'low', 3)
13. Random(b2, 'high', 0)
14. Random(b2, 'medium', 0)

There will be a `Random` model whose `rank` represents the correct count of authors of a book of a specific type.
for eg, If a book has Random(book, 'high', 20). then It means that there have to be 20 authors with type `high`. if there are more than or less than 20 authors then it's an error.
I want to filter those `Book` objects which are having this type of error.

Here `b1` has zero authors of type = low but it has Random object where rank of 'low' is 5. means there must be 5 authors of type low. `b1` has error.
but this is not in case of `b2`

How can I filter those Book objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try filter all the Random objects. Then using a for loop you can check if the `rank` and the number of authors of a type are equal for a book or not. Here is a code[untested] for the same. You can use [count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/).

```
all_random = Random.objects.all()
wrong_book=[]
for random in all_random:
    if Author.objects.filter(book=random.book,type=random.type).count() != random.rank:
        wrong_book.append(random.book)
result= set(wrong_book)
```

wrong_book is the list of book objects.

Comment: any method to do it with proper django query?

Comment: there is an error of duplicate book objects in wrong_book list. so we should use set here instead of list.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out a way to doing it with Django ORM.

```
high_queryset = Books.objects.annotate(t=Case(When(authors__option='high',
                            then=Count('authors', distinct=True)), default=Value('0'),output_field=PositiveIntegerField(),),) \
                            .filter( Q(randoms__option='high') & ~Q(t=F('randoms__value')))

medium_queryset = Books.objects.annotate(t=Case(When(authors__option='medium',
                            then=Count('authors', distinct=True)), default=Value('0'),output_field=PositiveIntegerField(),),) \
                            .filter( Q(randoms__option='medium') & ~Q(t=F('randoms__value')))

low_queryset = Books.objects.annotate(t=Case(When(authors__option='low',
                            then=Count('authors', distinct=True)), default=Value('0'),output_field=PositiveIntegerField(),),) \
                            .filter( Q(randoms__option='low') & ~Q(t=F('randoms__value')))


final_queryset = (high_queryset | medium_queryset | low_queryset).distinct()
```